# Ionic 2 - Keyboard action: enter instead of advance

Tags: angular, ionic2, ionic3

I have a login form on Ionic 2 which view is like this:

```
 <form #f="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="login(f)">
        <ion-list>
          <ion-item>
            <ion-label floating>E-mail</ion-label>
            <ion-input
              type="email"
              ngModel
              name="email"
              required></ion-input>
          </ion-item>
          <ion-item>
            <ion-label floating>Password</ion-label>
            <ion-input
              type="password"
              ngModel
              name="password"
              required></ion-input>
          </ion-item>
        </ion-list>
        <br>
        <button ion-button block type="submit" [disabled]="!f.valid">Enter</button>
        <br>
        <h2 class="text-center"><a (click)="forgotPassword()">Forgot your password? </a></h2>

      </form>
```

When the user is filling the form, the keyboard option is to advance (to next input). That is desirable on login input, but on password, think it should be the "enter" option (submit the form), but instead is advance too (and if you click on it, nothing happens). How could I change that so on when user is filling the password, the options is to enter (submit)?

EDIT:

Just to clarify, this is my login screen. That bottom right button "Avançar" (advance) is the one that I wanted to be "Enter" (submit the form)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For ionic 3 (since ionic3 was tagged), you can use **(keyup.enter)**

Example

```
<ion-input type="password" (keyup.enter)="submit()" required> </ion-input>
```

Comment: didn't worked for me. Updated the question with a screenshot